# How to maintain the list view to display last row

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view and i am setting list adapter every time some text is being sent.

My problem is, when a new message is populated in the list view, it shows the messages from the first.I want to make the list view to display last message when a new item is added to the list.

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using android:stackFromBottom